# Употребление слов "наклеить" и "приклеить"

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, паронимы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как верно: "Михаил, наклеив усы, вышел на сцену" или "Михаил, приклеив усы, вышел на сцену"? Есть ли здесь какие-либо правила, как с одеть/надеть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слова различаются *по употреблению*: **наклеивают** преимущественно что-либо *плоское* на поверхность чего-то другого; **приклеивают** же всё равно что, всё равно к чему, всё равно насколько аккуратно. Разная *сочетаемость с предлогами*: наклеивают "**на**", приклеивают "**к**".

**P.S.** В вашем примере большой разницы нет, но если бы Михаил приклеил себе не усы, а рога (объёмные предметы), то "*наклеил*" было бы не совсем удачно.

Answer (score 1):

В значении **"Прикрепить чем-л. липким к чему-л."** они синонимы. В Вашем случае можно использовать оба варианта.

Из словаря.

НАКЛЕИТЬ, -ею, -еишь; -еенный; сов. 1. что. **То же, что приклеить.** Н. марку на конверт. (Ожегов)

ПРИКЛЕИТЬ, -клею, -клеишь; св. что. 1. Прикрепить клеем или чем-л. клейким. П. объявление на доску, столб, стену. П. фотографию. Намертво п. П. пластырем. 
НАКЛЕИТЬ, -клею, -клеишь; св. 1. что. Прикрепить чем-л. липким к чему-л. Н. обои на стены.**(Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.).**

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

(1) Наклеить ― что и на что. (2)  Приклеить ― что, к чему и чем.

**Иногда глаголы взаимозаменяемы, но не всегда.**

**Наклеивают** что-то на плоскую поверхность, ножку к столу не наклеишь.

С другой стороны, при обсуждении дизайна предмета лучше подходит глагол ***наклеить*** (какие обои лучше наклеить), а  ***приклеить*** ― глагол более практичный (приклеить ― присоединить), когда описывается или привычный процесс, или обсуждается, чем лучше приклеить.

**Примеры:**

Влад зачем-то **наклеил усы** и теперь их картинно поглаживал. [Марина Вишневецкая. Вышел месяц из тумана (1997)] Он не узнал меня, хотя я изменил внешность только тем, что **наклеил** усы и надел пенсне… [Владлен Давыдов. Театр моей мечты (2004)]

Он... скинул для удобства казенный мундир и перед стенным зеркалом опытной рукой разрисовал себе сперва легкими морщинками лоб и углы рта, подвел затем брови, а в заключение **приклеил усы** и козлиную бородку. [В. П. Авенариус. Гоголь-гимназист (1897)]